# Jest beforeAll fetching from API done after describe executes so running tests for each fetched page fails

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to create jest tests that fetches pages data (url, component data and all info about what is on what page) from API in beforeAll - and then loop over them and test them with pupeteer - but because I have to make tests that react to what is being fetched - I have to use describe. But it seems only it() or test()  after beforeAll. Small, simplified example:

```
'use strict';
const helpers = require('./helpers');

describe('pages', () => {
    let livePages;
    beforeAll(async () => {
        const { key } = await helpers.login();
        const { pages } = await helpers.getPageList(key);
        livePages = pages.filter(page => page.pageState === 'live');
    });
    test('smoke test', () => {
        expect(livePages.length).not.toBe(0);
    });

    it('smoke test', () => {
        expect(livePages.length).not.toBe(0);
    });
    describe('smoke test', () => {
        livePages.forEach(page => {
            test('locale test', () => {
                expect(page.locale).toBe('de-DE');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and it fails with 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined' but both test() and it() passes (Tests: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total). 
Is there any workaround that would allow me to run specific tests for each fetched page?

Comment: try adding a long timeout to your beforeAll(()=>{},120000).  I just had a case where the test was getting run even though my awaits were never complete.  I think there is something in the framework that just allows the code to continue even though the awaits have not been filled.

Comment: `describe` blocks are executed before `beforeAll`, etc. You need to nest another `it` or `test` inside the `describe`. `describe` is a container for tests, not a test.

Comment: @TomW Unfortunately if I try to nest one it/test inside another it/test I get `Tests cannot be nested. Test "locale test" cannot run because it is nested within "test"`

Comment: Yes, you cannot do that, and you cannot asynchronously create tests in the way you want to. You’ll have to test all the live pages in a single test unfortunately. See also https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1670